Insulating interior walls
Is it okay to insulate my interior wall cavities with 1 inch blue insulation styrofoam and then r13 bat insulation on top of that before I sheetrock

You can, but the question is why.  Common reason is sound deading, but not sure if that is best.

R13 bats are 3.5 inches thick.  If you added 1 inch of Styrofoam, you would be compressing the bats and defeating some of the insulating properties and adding unnecessary cost.

What is the purpose and what concerns do you refer to by "okay"?

Styrofoam has much lower vapor permeability than fiberglass so if you put it on the outside, in winter it will kind of act like a vapor barrier and you may get condensation. In summer it will prevent condensation from drying. Unless you live in a climate where you need lots of air conditioning, vapor barrier should go on the inside.
